# NaNS produced when using the probit analysis in LC50 toxicity analysis

Tags: r, warnings, data-analysis

I have a dose/response relationship from the chronic toxicity test I have done and I intended to use a probit analysis (LC_probit function of the ecotox package) to calculate the LC50 value of the substance and after the test I have gotten no Confidence Intervals calculated and got this warning message:

"Warning message:
In sqrt(cl_part_2) : NaNs produced"

Originally my data was binary (0 - alive, 1 - dead) as each replicate had one daphnid in it. I grouped them together and created a proportional mortality for each concentration to solve the issue, however the problem still remained.

| Dose | Proportional mortality | Total replicates (n) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.4 | 10 |
| 0.6 | 0.5 | 10 |
| 1.2 | 0.5 | 10 |
| 2.4 | 0.888 | 9 |
| 4.8 | 0.555 | 9 |
| 9.6 | 0.5 | 10 |

Here is the code I used for this calculation:

```
library(ecotox)
rob1<-read.csv("robc14a.csv", stringsAsFactors = TRUE)
str(rob1)

rob_det<-LC_probit(prop~log10(dose), p=c(50), weights=total, data=rob1)
rob_det
```

Tried using the Spearman - Karber method to see if the problem persists and it did, and I can tell the problem probably lies inside the data itself but I cannot figure out where it is from possible layout problem or something else entirely.

Comment: So, after discussing with my professor, the problem seems to be that the data does not follow a sigmoidal dose-response relationship and when the test is calculating the Confidence Intervals, it ends up with negative values which freaks out the test when it wants to sqrt the values and results in error.

However knowing this I think using another test that does not see this would probably be better?

Comment: How can you have proportional mortality of 0.555 or 0.888 out of a total of 10 trials ... ?

Comment: You are right sir. It was 9 replicates and not 10 for those and I just mistyped it when making the table.

Comment: We can probably come up with a procedure to identify the LC50, but I'd like to confirm that LC50 is even a meaningful number for a dose-response curve that looks like this ... https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.3758/BF03194551.pdf talks about "an algorithm that can be used to monotonize an observed psychometric function when needed" (where the 'psychometric function' is your dose-response curve), but I'm not sure it makes sense when the curve is so violently non-monotonic. Is there a good explanation for what's going on at dose=2.4?

Comment: The only possible explanation I could come to is the fact that I disregarded the age of the daphnids I used in my toxicity study for my dissertation as time was already a sensitive issue with Covid regulations and thus it is a factor that some daphnids would be older than others and perish at more inconsistent times.